# Xamarin says no SDK, but it's there

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-ndk

I'm using VS2015, on Windows 7 Pro, and I'm trying to use the Xamarin tools.  In Tools->Options->Xamarin I have the appropriate Java, Android SDK, and Android NDK installed and the paths are correct.  I've attached a screen shot showing this.  I've tried changing those settings, which lets me know I changed it incorrectly, and changed it back and VS allowed the changes, thus me assuming they are correct.  And yet VS keeps reporting it cannot find the SDK, to verify the path.  I have done so multiple times, and I just cannot get this to work at all.

[image: Screen SHot showing Path Settings and the Actual Paths]

I've tried uninstall, re-installing, changing options, etc... And no matter what I cannot get it to work.  Do these paths also need to exist in my OS environment settings, such as the PATH?  And if so, these specific directories, or should it point to some sub-directory?

Comment: If there are Xamarin updates available, you may want to install those (Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > "Check Now"), then install JDK 1.8 as [Xamarin.Android 7.0 requires it to use the Android Nougat (API 24) APIs](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/).

Comment: I did the Check Now option, and it installed a new version of Xamarin. According to all the videos I've seen on how to use this, that should be the only think necessary.  I've never seen anything pointing to manually installing a bunch of stuff.  Is there some updated documentation somewhere pointing all this out?  My understanding was it was supposed to be all self-contained...

Comment: I installed JDK 1.8, and changed the path setting in VS, but I still get the same issues.  It still cannot find the Android SDK, even though it is there.

Comment: If you are using forms please check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64860/visual-studio-erro  and search stackoverflow questions for IDE0006

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin.Forms (yet), was just trying to do a blank android app.

Comment: If you expand the Warning in your Error List or read it in the `Build Output` it should mention something along the lines of what it's looking for. Chances are you don't have any Android APIs installed in the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Android SDK to include ver 24 (manually installed), Created a toolchains subdirectory in the NDK path, installed Xamarin Player manually, I think I got it all as it appears to work.  It w as a whole lot of head scratching and just trying crap over and over again.  I can't even give you a clear cut list of instructions on what I did to resolve this because it was a whole lot of trial and error.

Overall, less than pleased with VS2015, Xamarin and how this all works together.  Poorly documented, everything is pretty much a guessing game, and everything is needed to be done manually. What a P.O.S.  My co-workers are gonna hate trying to set this damn thing up correctly...